# Cannot set Spring profile through Maven profile

Tags: spring, maven, profile

This is my application-mysql.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXXX
    username: XX
    password: XX
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

This is my pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>mysql</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
```

Now I want to simple: `mvn clean install`.

Also tried `mvn clean install -Pdev`.

and get error when starting the Spring Boot application like it is not taking the application-mysql properties.

When I set in the application.properties

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

Then it works.

Comment: try to find out with `mvn help:effective-pom -Pdev` if the problem is that the maven profile doesn't get activated or that the maven profile does not trigger to activate the spring profile

Comment: @cyberbrain 

Seems like it is taking the profile, as the effective pom includes the profile.
Then I'm wondering if the spring.profiles.active is well set. I guess no.

</reporting>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        <property>
          <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
          <value>mysql</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>

Comment: `<property><name><value>` - invalid syntax, should be `<properties><property.name>value</property.name></properties>`

Comment: You are configuring the trigger to activate this _maven_ profile by the system property `spring.profiles.active`. 
Do you also start the application with maven?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing up Maven properties with System properties. The `<properties>` inside the pom can only be used within the context of that pom. So they are not being exposed as System properties, hence not being picked up by Spring.

Not sure how/why you are starting the application during build, I assume for a test.
What I suggest to do is to read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config which shows you how you can control the configuration under different conditions (without Maven).